# Passcode to access app

Tags: java, android

I want to password protect my app, so that when it is launched or resumed from background, a PIN must be entered. I have done this on iOS using a UIView that covers the screen and disappears when the correct PIN is typed in (Similar to the passcode that can be enabled in the Dropbox app). On Android, however, I am not sure how to proceed. If I create a passcode Fragment or Activity, I guess it can be removed simply by pushing the back button. I know that the back button can be reprogrammed, but I imagine that it could cause some unwanted effects. (like having to clear the back stack when passcode view is presented)

Verifying the PIN, doing the UI layout and all of that is OK, but the issue is how to present it (from a programmatical perspective). Is it recommended to cover the app with a Fragment, Activity or something else? How can I keep the user from using the app when the passcode view is present, but at all other times have no (side) effect on the app?

Comment: You can create a dialog and `setCanclable(fasle);` for it. close dialog when user enter correct PIN and hit ok button.

Comment: Thanks! Ideally I would like to create a custom view, so that I can modify the UI however I like, but your solution is a good backup if I cannot present a custom view-like solution securely :-)

Comment: You can customize a Dialog the way you want. You can also do this in an Activity. You can just disable the BACK button from that Activity by overriding `onBackPressed()` and ignoring the BACK button. This doesn't have any undesirable effects on your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override `onBackPressed()` of an Activity there will be no sideeffects on pressing the button. You can do this on your custom Activity that covers the Screen or on the MainActivity if you use a Fragment and check if the "LockFragment" is present or the app is in the unlocked state to react normal.

Activity Code:

```
@Override
onBackPressed(){
  if(check if your Fragment is present){
    //do noting
  } else {
    //react normal
    super.onBackpressed()
  }
}
```